# How do you extract exact mean/Guassian curvature values from Mesh?

Tags: meshlab

Once I calculate the mean/Gaussian curvature using say "pseudoinverse quadric fit" method, I am able to see the color map along my mesh, but am having trouble extracting those curvature values for every vertex. Of course, I could use the color scale to figure out what the curvature values are, but ultimately these values are coarse-grained due to the lack of resolution.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The "Compute curvature principal directions" filter writes scalar values to the vertex "quality" field; I would presume that these are the curvature values. You can save these values with the mesh when you export to a PLY file.